# Prevent IE11 for using cached API response when pressing browser's "Back" button

Tags: hash, internet-explorer-11, back-button

I am writing a React application, using hash routing (react router v3). I have discovered a bug where IE11 is using the cached API response when pressing the browser's 'Back' button. I am using the fetch API [with a polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

The headers I am sending with the initial request are as follows:

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'cache': 'no-store',
    'Expires': 0,
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

Any one know how to force IE11 to make a new API request in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a query parameter with `"expires=" + Date.now()` so that it will always be unique and cache will not be used. This approach works for IE11.